# Get a Result Set Based on Earliest Date in Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a query where I need to get all the latest Orders and their Dates by Sales Person.

```
var LatestOrders = (from a in ctx.Orders
join b in ctx.SalesPerson on a.ID equals b.FK_SalesPerson
where b.SalesPerson == "Name"
group a by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.OrderDate) into e
select e.Max(d => d.DateSubmitted));
```

ATM the query returns multiple different dates.

I need multiple records with the same dates.

e.g.

27/05/2020  Sally

27/05/2020  William

27/05/2020  Sarah

Comment: What is the definition of latest orders ? Orders placed in the last 1 hour ? 2 hours ? 24 hours ?3 months ? If you are looking for the orders, why are you grouping it ? just query the order table and order by the created date and take top(n) orders using `Take` method.

Comment: Latest order meaning, literally the newest order by date, not specific date. Thanks I will give that a try as well.

Comment: Providing the desired outcome would help a lot.